# Show enlarged image when hovering on top of everything else

Tags: html, css

On my web page I have a grid of images. When I hover the mouse over one of these images I want to show an enlarged version of this image. Currently I am doing that like this via CSS:

```css
.effectscale {
  border: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.effectscale:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

This works fine, however, now the enlarged version of an image is shown above all previous images, but below all following images in the grid. What I want is to show the enlarged version of the image on top of everything else, i.e. on top of all other images, even the following ones in the grid.

Additionally, when I hover over an image that is at the border of its parent `<div>`, then the enlarged version of the image is cut at the border of this div. But I also want to float that enlarged version of the image over **everything** else, so that even the border of the `<div>` would not prevent the whole image to be shown. How to achieve this?

Comment: Can you add some sort of working fiddle? Also, did you try `.effectscale:hover img { transform: scale(2); }` (depending on how you have your `HTML` set up)?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `z-index` as well as alignment in the hover styling section OR You can also use a combination of `z-index` and `display: block`.

Comment: Adding a `z-index` did not change anything.

Comment: @Matthias share enough code to demonstrate your issue (you can use fake image at https://placeimg.com/ or  https://picsum.photos/images ). So no need to wait untill someone guesses the right answer to your very case ;)

Comment: I guess then we have to wait for other alternative answer.